# How to get remaining Terminal Services Grace period Days using Get-CimInstance or Get-CimClass

Tags: remote-desktop

Since PowerShell 7 does not have the cmdlet Get-WmiObject, How do we get the Remaining Grace period days using Get-CimInstance ?

With WMI following was working fine but I cant seem to get the smae information using Get-CIMInstance:

`(Invoke-WmiMethod -PATH (gwmi -namespace root\cimv2\terminalservices -class win32_terminalservicesetting).__PATH -name GetGracePeriodDays).daysleft`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never Mind !! I have been able to get the information using CimInstance cmdlets below"

`(Invoke-CimMethod -InputObject (Get-CimInstance -Namespace root/CIMV2/TerminalServices -ClassName Win32_TerminalServiceSetting) -MethodName GetGracePeriodDays).DaysLeft`

[Here is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1VjqY.png)